# How do I know the 'meta_key' for ordering my custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I want to order my custom post type called sermons by sermon date, not the date entered.

See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

How do I know the `meta_key` of my custom post type? Is this the ID, or name?

Answer (score 0):

What is "sermon date", is it the custom field? If so, your meta_key is the name of your custom field used for that date. If not, how are you getting the sermon date?

Might be something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sermons',
    'meta_key'  => 'sermon_date',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'meta_type' => 'DATE'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Meta keys are arbitrary and not connected to Custom Post Type definition.

For *any* post custom meta fields can be created with *any* valid string key.

So basically discovery of the keys is completely up to documentation and/or reading source code.